# How to handle quotes inside strings when writing parsers?

Tags: php, string, parsing

Example:

```
"abcdef\"gh"
```

The parser spec states that the string begins with `"` and ends with `"`. But also it should ignore escaped quotes like `\"`

What's the best way to handle this situation when writing a parser?

I was thinking to look behind, and if the previous character is `\` I simply ignore the quote. But is this the best way? Because it seems a little fishy to me

Comment: There is no *best* way. Of course you can manually traverse such a string to tokenize it, but usually a regex suffices. It entirely depends on the permitted string syntax however. Is this about PHP strings?

Comment: or while parsing forward, if you encounter a ``\``, you ignore the following char, no matter what it is.

Comment: If done with a state machine, it's pretty trivial to parse. You consume each character one by one, when you encounter a ``\``, you go into "just take next character literally" state and then snap back out of it.

Comment: You're right, didn't think it would be so easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning backwards is possible, but tricky, because you might have some sequence of escaped characters:

```
"This is a backslash: \"\\\""
```

It's usually easier to parse forwards than backwards. A simple regular expression which matches the contents of a double-quoted string with escapes would be:

```
([^"]|\\.)*
```

But that only helps you recognize the contents of the string. In practice, you will usually want to *interpret* the contents of the string, which might include transformations such as changing `\n` to a newline, or even changing `\u00D1` to the utf-8 sequence for `Ñ` (C3 91).